# Unrecoverable cycle resolving import

Tags: scala

In my test code I had this repetitive pattern of generating UUIDs in the companion objects, for example `val userId: String = UUID.randomUUID().toString`. In order to reduce writing this out each time, I've moved this to a trait:

```scala
trait UUIDGenerator  {
  def uuid(): UUID = UUID.randomUUID()
  def stringifiedUUID(): String = uuid().toString
}
```

I then make my test classes' companion objects extend this trait, e.g.:

```scala
object MySpec extends UUIGenerator {

  ...
  private val userId: String = stringifiedUUID()
}
```

My test class is not really relevant but they used `userId` a few times:

```scala
class MySpec extends Specification with AfterEach with BeforeAll {
  ...
  // not really relevant
}
```

However the code now doesn't compile with the following error:

```sh
encountered unrecoverable cycle resolving import.
[error] Note: this is often due in part to a class depending on a definition nested within its companion.
[error] If applicable, you may wish to try moving some members into another object.
[error] import ca.vasigorc.MySpec._
```

What is the problem here, and most importantly what is the proper solution? Renaming all companion objects seems like a worse hack then the current repetition.

Comment: Couldn’t you make the spec extend the trait instead of the companion object?

Comment: The field is in the companion object along with other constants for the test classes. This is generally a recommended approach. I did try to mixing the trait into test classes and add `self: UUIGGenerator => ` to companion object, but a) that lead to another error, b) looks convoluted

Comment: That error is very weird and I have never seen it before, can you create a little Github repo that reproduces the problem and share it here? You may also try to see if **Scastie** alone is able to reproduce it.

Comment: I think what's in your test class actually is relevant. I can't reproduce this from the code provided (even if I add references to `userId` in the spec). Where are you placing  that import statement?

Comment: I was able to get this error by placing `import ca.vasigorc.MySpec._` outside the class definition (at the top level). Putting it inside the class definition solves it.

Comment: You have to remember than `X` companion object will have some of its code defined in `A` as `static`. Which means that cyclical reference might cause issues with `ClassLoader`s (e.g. it might deadlock), and Scala compiler probably tries to defend against that here.

Comment: Hey @TimMoore thank you! It was indeed the placement of the import that caused the issue! Would you mind copying your comment to an answer, so I can up and mark it?

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok, thank you. I understand that companion object fields will be compiled to static fields, but I haven't understood how is this related to cyclical references. Could you please provide a link so that I could read-up on this?

Comment: Things like [this](https://twitter.com/shipilev/status/1471216975485579267) or [this](https://twitter.com/koppcapp/status/1471238981601873930).